# How can I update a sub-sub-doc in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Below are all the schemas I created. I used the method `findByIdAndUpdate()` for adding new posts to the `Club` Schema. Now, I want to add comments to a post. I tried doing the same for comments as well but it didn't work. I also tried [this](https://coderwall.com/p/6v5rcw/querying-sub-documents-and-sub-sub-documents-in-mongoose), and I got the error mentioned below. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema  = mongoose.Schema;
var Post = require('./posts');

var clubSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    abbreviation: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    followers: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    posts: [Post.Schema]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Club', clubSchema);

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema  = mongoose.Schema;
var Comment = require('./comments');

var postSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    createdBy: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    comments: [Comment.Schema],
    votes: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema  = mongoose.Schema;

var commentSchema = new Schema({
    head: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Comment', commentSchema);
```

I tried this.

```
app.post("/all_comments/:id", function(req, res) {
        var new_comment = new Comment({
            head: req.body.head,
            content: req.body.content
        });

        Club.findById(req.params.id, function(err, club) {
            var posts = club.posts;
            // console.log(posts);
            for(i in posts) {
                if(posts[i]._id == req.body.id) {
                    console.log(posts[i]);
                    posts[i].comments.push(new_comment);
                    posts[i].save(function(err) {
                        if(err)
                            console.log(err);
                    });
                    club.save(function(err) {
                        if(err)
                            console.log(err);
                        else
                            res.send("Successful");
                    });
                }
            }
        });

    });
```

The error I'm getting

`TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'save'`

Comment: All the schemas are in different files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't dig too deep on this but I do notice that you are trying to access the model's schema with: `Comment.Schema`. According to the Mongoose docs (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-schema) that property should be lower case, e.g. `Comment.schema`.

Try logging each to the console and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to call `posts[i].save()`.

You can call `club.save()` only once, after doing all the pushing.

Comment: I also did that, but the comments are getting saved directly in the ``Club`` object and not in the comments array of the post.

Comment: Ah, must be something to do with the fact that you are turning the embedded docs into Mongoose Models. In the first example at http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html you can see that only the schema should be used for embedded docs. No model is involved.